# Multiplicativity of expected value

Tags: probability, expectation

It is stated that $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$ only if $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, thus $Cov(X,Y) = 0$.

The covariance of a random variable with itself is just it's variance, which is to say $Cov(X,X) = Var(X)$.

So it stands to reason that $E[X]E[X] \neq E[X^2]$, based on the covariance of $X$ being equal to $Var(X)$, which is probably not $0$.

However, on a homework question I've found it stated that:
$E[(X-Y)]^2 = E[X^2] + E[Y^2] - 2E[XY]$, given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent variables.

It was further stated later in the question that
$E[(X-Y)]^2 = E[X^2] - 2E[XY] + (Var(Y) + E(Y^2))$

Which makes me think it was not a mistake with parenthesis placement.

Should it not be:

$E[(X-Y)]^2 = (E[X]-E[Y])(E[X]-E[Y]) = E[X]^2 + E[Y]^2 - 2E[XY]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,
$$(X-Y)^2 = X^2 + Y^2 - 2XY$$
Hence, by linearity of $\mathbb{E}$,
$$\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]-2\mathbb{E}[XY]$$
Independence of $X$ and $Y$ is not required for the above. (Notice that I didn't use this assumption at all.)

Looking at the work you have, what you basically said was that
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2]&=\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)(X-Y)] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X-Y]\cdot\mathbb{E}[X-Y]\quad\text{(not true!)}
\end{align}$$
To split the expected values via multiplication, you must have independence of each multiplicative term. This isn't true, because $X-Y$ is obviously not independent of $X-Y$: observe that $$\text{Cov}(X-Y, X-Y)=\text{Var}[X-Y] = \text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)-2\cdot\text{Cov}(X, Y)$$
which - assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent -  as long as $\text{Var}(X)$ and $\text{Var}(Y)$ are not $0$, $\text{Cov}(X-Y, X-Y) \neq 0$, hence $X-Y$ is not independent of $X-Y$.

Comment: I was hesitant to use $E[(X-Y)]^2 = E[(X-Y)^2]$, for the same reason that $E[X]^2 =/= E[X^2]$. Why does it work here?

Comment: @pajkatt $\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)]^2 \neq \mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2]$; I'm not sure where you get this impression. Please reread what I have above about the expected value splittling via multiplication.

Comment: You said by the linearity of E, $$\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]-2\mathbb{E}[XY]$$, is this not identical to the answer of $E[(X-Y)]^2$ that I said was stated on the homework? At least, that is where I get the impression.

Comment: Yes, @pajkatt; Clarinetist is saying that your homework is *wrong*, since: $$\begin{array}{c}\mathsf E[(X-Y)^2]=\mathsf E[X^2]+\mathsf E[Y^2]-2\mathsf E[XY]\qquad\\ \mathsf E[(X-Y)]^2=\mathsf E[X]^2+\mathsf E[Y]^2-2\mathsf E[X]\mathsf E[Y]\\ \hline \mathsf{Var}[X-Y]= \mathsf{Var}[X]+\mathsf{Var}[Y]-2\,\mathsf{Cov}[X,Y] \end{array}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp just to cover all my bases, it wouldn't make a difference if $X$ was $N(0,1)$ and $Y$ was $Exp(1)$, would it?

Comment: @pajkatt No; it is a general result.